# Can I use old cloth-jacketed wiring to power a new light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, remodeling, old-house

I removed some wood paneling in a hallway closet and found this wire bundle between the studs. Is this electrical wires? Can I reuse this to install a light source for the closet?

[image]

Comment: Is the wire hot? That's the first question. It's not nutted off so my guess is it might be old work that they just clipped the old wire and left it there.

Comment: do you have any junction boxes in the area?

Comment: @machavity how do I check if it's hot? If it's just old work that was clipped off does it mean I can reuse it?

Comment: @CFella. There wasn't any thing between the studs other than the wire. The wire was coming out of the corner of the ceiling. Should I check the attic for junction boxes? What would a junction box mean?

Comment: What country are you in? In the USA, junction boxes are exposed so you can access the wires. It wouldn’t be anywhere hidden. Possibly the other end of those wires are in the junction box. Do a quick google image search of the word junction box.

Comment: @shellylei A [contactless power detecotr like this one](https://www.amazon.com/Milwaukee-2202-20-Voltage-Detector-Light/dp/B004CZ08LU) would suffice

Comment: @Cfella I'm in the US. I googled junction box and it says it might be in the attic. I can go check this weekend. If there is no junction box does that mean I can not use this wire? Or does it just mean I need to add one?

Comment: no, it doesn't mean you can't use the wire. You just need to find the other end of it to hook it back up to a live circuit. I was thinking the other end may be in a junction box. It may be up in the attic.

Comment: Actually, depending on how old your house is, I guess the junction boxes may be hidden if they were installed before the code change.